# Is there an existing class or structure in .NET that can serve my purpose?

Tags: .net, object, dictionary, conditional-statements

I am working on a function that is searching text for certain things. There is a large variation in what it is looking for. For instance I am trying to find a string "one two three". It can show up as "on tw o three", "one tw  three", "one    two     three", "ne two three" etc... and so on and so on.

I was thinking if I should create an object or a structure that would contain all those possible values. Would creating a dictionary object for each of the string I am looking for (there are about a hundred) make sense? Is there a better approach?

So far I am using if else statements and they are getting very bulky - each contains 3-6 conditions.

Any thoughts? thanks

Comment: Virtually any type of enumerable collection would work.

Comment: Look up [*Levenshtein Distance*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight!

Comment: How could I utilize enum collection in the if statement?    so far I have  if str="one two three" or str="on two  three" or str="ne two three" or str="one  two   three" then                                                                 end if                                                               and enum:                                                            Enum test
 "one two three"
 "on two  three" 
        "ne two three" 
        "one  two   three" 
    End Enum